# Display data from DB to ajaxToolkit LINE CHART (Ajax control Toolkit v20.1) Using ASP.NET Webform C# (Dissertation Question)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

So, I have some data in my database and I want to display them in a Line chart.
I am getting 2 errors when using 2 different approaches.
Please refer below.

Am stuck, please help.

In my database I have data such as

| month A | total_collected_amount B | Admincut |
| --- | --- | --- |
| November | 78.6000 | 2541.4000 |
| October | 24.0000 | 776.0000 |
| September | 2522.4000 | 81557.6000 |

And the SQL is

```
SELECT 
    DATENAME(MONTH, pay_date) AS month,
    SUM(pay_admin_fee_mur) AS total_collected_amount,
    SUM(pay_amount_mur) AS Admincut
FROM 
    tbl_payment

WHERE
    tbl_payment.cha_id IS NOT NULL
    AND
    FORMAT(pay_date,'yyyy') = '2023'
GROUP BY 
    DATENAME(MONTH, pay_date), YEAR(pay_date)
ORDER BY 
    month;
```

My ASPX page is

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">

    <ajaxToolkit:LineChart ID="LineChart1" runat="server" BackColor="64, 0, 0"   
        BackGradientStyle="LeftRight" Height="550px" Palette="None"   
        PaletteCustomColors="192, 0, 0" Width="550px" ChartType="Basic" BaseLineColor="black">
        <Series>
            <ajaxToolkit:LineChartSeries LineColor="Darkblue" Name="Amount collected" Data=""/>           
             <ajaxToolkit:LineChartSeries LineColor="Maroon" Name="Admin cut" Data=""/>            
        </Series>           
    </ajaxToolkit:LineChart>
</asp:Content>
```

The Code-behind: Try 1 with error.

```
    public partial class charityeventanalysis : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private string _conString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FARMSdb"].ConnectionString;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                // Fetch data from the database
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_conString))
                {
                    string query = "SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, pay_date) AS month, SUM(pay_admin_fee_mur) AS total_collected_amount, SUM(pay_amount_mur) AS Admincut FROM tbl_payment WHERE tbl_payment.cha_id IS NOT NULL AND FORMAT(pay_date,'yyyy') = '2023' GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH, pay_date), YEAR(pay_date) ORDER BY month;";

                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                    {
                        connection.Open();

                        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                string month = reader["month"].ToString();
                                decimal totalCollectedAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["total_collected_amount"]);
                                decimal adminCut = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["Admincut"]);

                                // Add data to the LineChart series ******* ERROR HERE *******
                                LineChart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(month, totalCollectedAmount);
                                LineChart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(month, adminCut);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                LineChart1.ChartTitle = "Yearly collection amount MUR (Rs)";
            }
        }

    }
```

Error underline for both at Points: saying "LineChartSeries does not contain a definition for Points and no accessible extension method Points accepting a first argument of type LineChartSeries could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assemble reference?)"

[image]

The Code-behind: Try 2 with error.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                // Fetch data from the database
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_conString))
                {
                    string query = "SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, pay_date) AS month, SUM(pay_admin_fee_mur) AS total_collected_amount, SUM(pay_amount_mur) AS Admincut FROM tbl_payment WHERE tbl_payment.cha_id IS NOT NULL AND FORMAT(pay_date,'yyyy') = '2023' GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH, pay_date), YEAR(pay_date) ORDER BY month;";

                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                    {
                        connection.Open();

                        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                string month = reader["month"].ToString();
                                decimal totalCollectedAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["total_collected_amount"]);
                                decimal adminCut = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["Admincut"]);

                                // Add data to the LineChart series ******* ERROR HERE *******
                                LineChart1.Series[0].Data += totalCollectedAmount + ",";
                                LineChart1.Series[1].Data += adminCut + ",";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Remove the trailing comma from the Data property ******* ERROR HERE *******
                LineChart1.Series[0].Data = LineChart1.Series[0].Data.TrimEnd(',');
                LineChart1.Series[1].Data = LineChart1.Series[1].Data.TrimEnd(',');

                LineChart1.ChartTitle = "Yearly collection amount MUR (Rs)";
            }
```

---

Error saying: Error "cannot implicitly convert string to decimal for  LineChart1.Series[0].Data += totalCollectedAmount + ","; LineChart1.Series[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNm7A.png).Data += adminCut + ",";"

[image]

AND error:

"decimal[] does not contain a definition for TrimEnd and no accessible extension method TrimEnd accepting a first argument of type decimal[] could be found(are you missing a using directive or an assemble reference?)"

[image]

Comment: It's off-topic, but your SQL is using an inefficient technique to group-by-month. You should use `GROUP BY YEAR( pay_date ), MONTH( pay_date )` instead of using `FORMAT`  or `DATENAME` (the `FORMAT` function is very slow, specifically, as it calls-out to the CLR every time it's used, whereas `CONVERT` (with the `style:` parameter set) is _native_.

Comment: Also, instead of `WHERE YEAR( pay_date ) = 2023` - it's much faster to do `WHERE pay_date >= '2023-01-01' AND pay_date < '2024-01-01'` because it can use indexes for a range query. This is called SARGability: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/162263/what-does-the-word-sargable-really-mean

Comment: `LineChart1.Series[0].Data += totalCollectedAmount + ",";` <-- Please explain what you're trying to do here...

Comment: You should remove all calls to `Convert` in your code - _there is no reason to use `System.Convert` for numeric value processing_ in .NET (it's a holdover from VB6 days). Instead, use `.Parse` and `.TryParse` methods on the actual types you want to use - and _always_ specify a `CultureInfo` - oitherwise you'll end up with unexpected formatting (as ASP.NET uses the browser's `Accept-Language` header to set culture, which is not set correctly for most people, IME)

Comment: @Dai thanks for the first one its noted. But for the second SQL, I will be using parameterized Query for a Dropdown to select the years in order to query my DB. that why for now its 2023 when correcting it it will be kind like pay_date=@ddl

Comment: You can use `WHERE pay_date >= DATEFROMPARTS( @year, 1, 1 ) AND pay_date < DATEFROMPARTS( @year + 1, 1, 1 )`

Comment: `Convert.ToDecimal(reader["total_collected_amount"]);` <-- Assuming that your column type is already `decimal` (or `money`) (_right?_) - so there's no need to use `Convert.ToDecimal`. Use the `DbDataReader.GetDecimal` method.

Comment: @Dai I need help to display the data from database to the Linechart. This is very important for. For Now I have only used code from what CHATGPT gave?

Comment: ...you're passing-off ChatGPT's output as your own work for your _dissertation_ coursework? There's a word for that: _plagiarism_. Please explain yourself.

Comment: I have never used a LineChart. So am searching but all links are different. None have used this approach.

Comment: Why not just look at the actual sources? https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/blob/master/AjaxControlToolkit/LineChart/LineChart.cs - `LineChartSeries` is here: https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/blob/d3ad8d0822c4584b8ebf54d041bb514b0007d1c2/AjaxControlToolkit/LineChart/LineChartSeries.cs#L9 - the `Data` property is a mutable `Decimal[]` property. You'll need to read all of your data into a `Decimal[]` first then overwrite the property _once_.

Comment: @Dai yes I have already gone through this. Its using A FORM that is he is build his form for an application.

Comment: So what problem are you having then? I just told you everything you need to fix all of the problems/errors you're getting.

Comment: Am build a website Not a FORM (using form builder). its different. The packages are different.

Comment: @Dai I got my answer my Lord, I love you.

Comment: I am incapable of feeling love.